# Spark Streaming: Text data source supports only a single column

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, spark-streaming

I am consuming `Kafka` data and then stream the data to `HDFS`.

The data stored in `Kafka` topic `trial` is like:

```
hadoop
hive
hive
kafka
hive
```

However, when I submit my codes, it returns:

Exception in thread "main"

```
org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Text data source supports only a single column, and you have 7 columns.;
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = 2f3c7433-f511-49e6-bdcf-4275b1f1229a, runId = 9c0f7a35-118a-469c-990f-af00f55d95fb]
Current Committed Offsets: {KafkaSource[Subscribe[trial]]: {"trial":{"2":13,"1":13,"3":12,"0":13}}}
Current Available Offsets: {KafkaSource[Subscribe[trial]]: {"trial":{"2":13,"1":13,"3":12,"0":14}}}
```

My question is: as shown above, the data stored in `Kafka` comprises only ONE column, why the program says there are `7 columns` ?

Any help is appreciated.

---

My `spark-streaming` codes:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder.master("local[4]")
  .appName("SpeedTester")
  .config("spark.driver.memory", "3g")
  .getOrCreate()

val ds = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "192.168.95.20:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "trial")
  .option("startingOffsets" , "earliest")
  .load()
  .writeStream
  .format("text")
  .option("path", "hdfs://192.168.95.21:8022/tmp/streaming/fixed")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint")
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is explained in the [Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html):

> Each row in the source has the following schema:
>
> Column    Type
>
> key   binary
>
> value     binary
>
> topic     string
>
> partition     int
>
> offset    long
>
> timestamp     long
>
> timestampType     int

Which gives exactly seven columns. If you want to write only payload (value) select it and cast to string:

```scala
spark.readStream
   ...
  .load()
  .selectExpr("CAST(value as string)")
  .writeStream
  ...
  .awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Thanks. I saw this part but did not realize it.